# Fix order of users in greeter?

Tags: greeter

Is it possible to change  (and fix) the order that users are listed in on the greeter screen for a single machine?

Answer (score 1):

What does “fixing” look like here? I know that it's more of a underlying system thing so for the greeter to do its own sorting would require some custom code.

---

Originally posted at https://jacky.wtf/2022/6/IVlj, manually POSSE'd.